# Prevent deadlock by running a Task synchronously - Windows Service

Tags: c#, task

I read that sometimes that calling directly a `Task` can lead to a deadlock of the main thread.

Here's my async method:

```
public async Task<List<JobsWithSchedules>> fillJobsAsync()
{
    IOlapJobAccess jobAccess = new OlapJobAccess(_proxy, CentralPointPath);
    List<OlapJob> jobs = await jobAccess.GetAllJobsAsync();
    List<JobsWithSchedules> quartzJobs = null;
    if (jobs != null)
    {
        quartzJobs = fillQuartzJobs(jobs);
    }
    return quartzJobs;
}
```

I tried a lot of ways to run this task in a sync function. Here's some examples:

```
public void syncFoo1()
{
    var fillJobsTask = fillJobsAsync().ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && task.Result != null)
        {
            List<JobsWithSchedules> quartzJobs = task.Result;
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
    });
    fillJobsTask.Wait();
}

public void syncFoo2()
{
    Task.Run(() => fillJobsAsync()).ContinueWith((task) =>
    {
        if (task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion && task.Result != null)
        {
            List<JobsWithSchedules> quartzJobs = task.Result;
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            //...
        }
    });
}
```

I want to know which is better solution to run the `async` method synchronously in the `syncFoo()` without causing deadlocks. Should I do it like in `syncFoo2()`?

PS: `syncFoo()` is called from a a windows service `onStart()` and `onStop()`.

Comment: Why do you want to call an async method synchronously? Why not expose a synchronous overload?

Comment: fillJobsAsync calls a wcf service

Comment: If its a WCF service it has synchronous endpoints as well.

Comment: @billybob: You generally do *not* want to call synchronous methods from a Win32 service `OnStart` - especially not when they're doing network I/O - because that can cause your service to timeout. Why not just call it asynchronously and save the task in a variable?

Comment: @Stephen Cleary: Do you suggest to make all my wcf calls async in my service? But At the start of the service I need to make sure that all the jobs are filled, before doing anything else.

Comment: @billybob: That's not how Win32 services are supposed to work. `OnStart` needs to return immediately. If you want to kick off a thread or something then do `Task.Run`.

Comment: Good, thanks for the hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's in a Windows service, the task should never run synchronously as [Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263693/stephen-cleary) suggested. I changed it to be async and it's working fine.